# Configure javafx-maven-plugin to create jar file without version number

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I cannot stop my javafx-maven-plugin to insert the version number into the jars file name. I tried to set finalName to "${pom.artifactId}" but that doesn't help.

What can I do?

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
      <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>8.1.4</version>
      <configuration>
        <mainClass>application.Main</mainClass>
        <jfxAppOutputDir>${project.build.directory}</jfxAppOutputDir>
        <finalName>${pom.artifactId}</finalName>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>create-jfxjar</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>build-jar</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: I updated the javafx-maven-plugin to version 8.8.3 and replaced pom.artifactId by project.artifactId but it still does not work.

Comment: What filenames do you mean? Can you provide some reproducable project for this? Maybe you want to open an issue on the github project. **Disclaimer:** I'm the maintainer of the javafx-maven-plugin.

Answer (score 1):

It is an old question, but:

1.Insert final jar Name in this way:

```
   <build>
        <finalName>your.customname.without.versionNumber</finalName>
```

2.Edit javafx-maven-plugin configuration, add this inside the configuration tag:

```
     <jfxMainAppJarName>${project.build.finalName}.jar</jfxMainAppJarName>
```

The complete configuration should looks like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>8.8.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <jfxMainAppJarName>${project.build.finalName}.jar</jfxMainAppJarName>
        <mainClass>com.my.amazingapp.MainClassName</mainClass>
        <vendor>The Tiger Programmer</vendor>
        <manifestAttributes>
             <developer>Me</developer>
             <contact>me@company.com</contact>
        </manifestAttributes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now if your finalName is "MyAmazingProject", after you run `mvn clean jfx:jar` you will find a file MyAmazingProject.jar under

> /target/jfx/app/MyAmazingProject.jar

This jar is a executable jar with Manifest Info.